# Como pegar dados retornados de uma requisição post AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$http.post('data.php').success(function(data) {
    return data;
}).error(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Como manipular os dados vindos dessa requisição?

Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
var data = $scope.get_notas();
```

Mas quando vou utilizar a variável **data** ela me retorna *undefined*

Comment: Porque nõ usas simplesmente o código logo no `success`? Por exemplo `console.log(data)` em vez de `return data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a chamada http é assíncrona. Uma forma de resolver seria reescrever a sua função `get_notas` de forma que esta execute uma função de callback:

```
$scope.get_notas = function(callback) {
    $http.post('data.php')
        .success(callback)
        .error(function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }); 
}
```

E ao chamá-la, passar a função que deve ser executada quando completar a requisição:

```
$scope.get_notas(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```